# Pulling info from one webpage and using it in my js program

Tags: javascript, json

Background: I am starting a js program for March Madness and I am trying to figure out how to pull the info from one website and use that info to fill in all my data in my program. For example, I want to pull all the shooting percentages, rebounds, steals, blocks, turnovers, etc.. from one website and then use that data to compare two teams in my program. How would I go about doing this? So far I've tried to convert the webpage into a JSON string and then manipulate that string, but it's not working so well.

```
var getBkpgArray = JSON.parse("table": {
            "class": "table table-striped table-bordered sticky-enabled",
            "thead": {
             "tr": {
              "th": [
               "Rank",
               "Team",
               "GM",
               "BLKS",
               "BKPG"
              ]
             }
            },
            "tbody": {
             "tr": [
              {
               "class": "odd",
               "td": [
                "1",
                {
                 "a": {
                  "href": "/schools/minnesota",
                  "content": "Minnesota"
                 }
                },
                "33",
                "224",
                "6.8"
               ])
```

First i'm trying to parse this data into an array

Comment: You should post a minimal verifiable example of the data you're trying to parse and what you've tried already, else we can't help you.

Comment: I converted the website into a JSON string use YQL.

Comment: You're still not showing what you've tried already and your question is still unclear about what you want to achieve (apart from what you're trying to do with your program, unless you are actually asking us to make the program for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web scraping can be really hard. You're getting data in a format that can change at any time. The data is structured inside HTML which might be very difficult to parse: in your example, the element containing blocks isn't labeled with a class or in some other way, you only know that from the structure of the table.

You might do something like:

```
// this array contains all the stat categories, make it lowercase
var categories = getBkpgArray['thead']['tr']['th'].map(String.toLowerCase());
// this will make an array of objects with team info
var teams = getBkpgArray['tbody']['tr'].reduce(function (acc, val, idx) {
    var team_array = val['td'];
    // go over each team category and give it the right category label
    var team_object = team_array.reduce(function (acc, val, idx) {
        var category_name = categories[idx];
        // if the category is 'team' get nested team name
        var category_val = (category_name === 'team') ? val['a']['content'] : val;
        acc[category_name] = category_value;
    }, {});
    acc.push(team_object);
}, []);
// the result is an array of team objects that look like this:
// {
//     'rank': '1',
//     'team': 'Minnesota',
//     'gm': '33',
//     'blks': '224',
//     'bkpg': '6.8'
// }
```

But there are lots of other ways to manipulate the data. If you're not familiar, read up on JavaScript `Array` methods, like [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), `Array.map()`, `Array.forEach()`, etc. These will help you process any useful data you get into a more convenient form. But always remember that the process is inherently fragile, as the table/page structure you're retrieving could change suddenly. For more info on that, in a Ruby context (but the principles are language independent) you can start here http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/web-scraping/ and research further.

The other option is to get NCAA data from a structured API, but that can be very expensive: http://developer.sportradar.com/pricing#basic-4

Remember that you should only ask questions here that are pretty specific: "I need to do something, here are the ways I tried to do it, this way breaks exactly like this, I tried these other ways to fix it, but I'm stuck." Don't just ask "Can you tell me how to do my work for me?" Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry the question wasn't specific enough.

Comment: No problem! Please accept this answer if it offered a good direction to go in.